# Adding files to stripe connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add some files (identity documents) to stripe to create a connected account, but I'm having trouble with uploading them from client side to stripe. My backend is in Node.js and the Stripe documentation says it should use this format:

```
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe('stripeAPIKEY');
var fp = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/a/file.jpg');
var file = await stripe.files.create({
  purpose: 'identity_document',
  file: {
    data: fp,
    name: 'file.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpg',
  },
});
```

I need to upload the file data (the variable fp), but I can't seem to get the relevant path for when the user uploads their document in the client side in Javascript. Here is my function call to Stripe:

```
export const uploadPersonIdFile = async (identityDocument: any) => {
    const fp = fs.readFileSync(identityDocument);
    const personId = await stripe.files.create({
        purpose: 'identity_document',
        file: {
            data: fp,
            name: 'idDocument.jpg',
            type: 'image/jpg',
        },
    });
    return personId; 
}
```

My client side looks like this:

```
        const inpFileU = $("#utilityButton");
        const previewImage = $("#image-preview__image-U"); 
        const previewDefaultText = $("#image-preview__default-text-U");

        inpFileU.change(function(){
            const file = this.files[0];
            if(file){
                const reader = new FileReader();
                previewImage.css("display", "block");
                reader.addEventListener("load", function(){
                    previewImage.attr("src", this.result);
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                utilityFileName = file.name;

                await uploadMerchantUtilityDocument({
                    utilityDocument: utilityFileName
                }).then((result) => {
                    /** @type {any} */
                    const data = result.data;
                    const textData = data.text;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(textData));
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error message: " + error.message);
                    console.log("Error details: " + error.details);
                });

            } else {
              console.log('no file');
            }
        });
```

I upload the file and then the error message response I keep getting is this:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'insuranceImage.jpeg'

How should I upload my file? I think my fp variable is wrong, but I don't know what to replace it with

Comment: Can you clarify which part the code you've provided throws that error? Based on the error I suspect that it's this line `const fp = fs.readFileSync(identityDocument);` and that the path you're providing isn't pointing to the file's location correctly.

Comment: Yeah exactly that - it's throwing an error on the client side, but it is that line of code in server side that's throwing it off

Comment: Are you actually writing the file that you upload anywhere in your code? Can you also show how you are calling `uploadPersonIdFile` so that it is clearer what the value of `identityDocument` is

Comment: "*My client side looks like this*" - nothing there calls your `uploadPersonIdFile` Stripe code. How are you doing that?

Comment: it's called inside the function uploadMerchantUtilityDocument. It's the only function inside that function (there's nothing else inside uploadMerchantUtilityDocument. Bit confusing, sorry!

Comment: The Stripe code is looking for a file on your server disk.  But there is no code here, AFAICT, that saves the uploaded file to your server disk.  As previously asked in an earlier comment - are you actually saving that uploaded file to your server disk, and if so, can you show that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a while I was helped by a pro online. Here's what he did (because stripe's documentation isn't too great on file uploading)...

I created a base64 variable from FileReader(), which came from creating an array `base64String = []` This array took hold of the result from reader.load, like so:

```
reader.addEventListener("load", function(){
      base64String.push(this.result);
});
```

This base64String array was then used as the identityDocument variable for the backend function.

So my base64 variable in the client-side kept on starting with 'image/jpeg; base64,' and I needed to get rid of that. No point using the fs.readFileSync as we're not uploading a file to stripe, we're uploading raw base64 data. So, the following code in node.js fits in well to solve this:

```
const parts = utilityDocument.split(",");
const base64 = parts[1];
const buffer = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");
```

so the full function that calls to stripe is so:

```
export const uploadPersonIdFile = async (uid: any, identityDocument: any) => {
    const parts = identityDocument.split(",");
    const base64 = parts[1];
    const buffer = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");
    const personId = await stripe.files.create({
        purpose: 'identity_document',
        file: {
            data: buffer,
            name: 'identity.jpg',
            type: 'image/jpg',
        },
    });
    await updateMerchantId(uid, { idDocument: personId.id });
    return personId; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you are uploading files from the client to the server and from the server you want to upload to stripe API. In this case, when you read a file with `fs` default encoding is `utf8` but maybe when the file uploaded it was encoded as base64. I do not know too much about jquery. Check how it was encoded, so use the correct encoding.

```
  const image= fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});
```

I think somehow the image is broken. If the image path is correct, just manually place an image in that directory, and then read from it as `utf8` encoding.

- since u got this error `base64 string is too large to process in fs.readFileSync` which means your path is correct.

  ```
  reader = fs.createReadStream('imagePath', {
    flag: 'a+',
    // then try this to base64
    encoding: 'UTF-8',
    start: 5,
    end: 64,
    highWaterMark: 16
  });

  // Read and display the file data on console
  reader.on('data', function (chunk) {
     console.log(chunk);
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error and the comment it looks like the path you're providing to `readFileSync` isn't pointing to where the file you're trying to read exists. From the error it looks like you're passing `insuranceImage.jpeg` and that the system can't find that file.

Try confirming whether the relative path you're providing is correct, or construct and provide an absolute path instead.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how do I send an absolute path? I’ve tried path.resolve(__dirname, ‘identityDocument’) but that didn’t work

Comment: I would try had coding the path first before trying to do any dynamic path resolution, similar to the line that you provided in the example code:  
`var fp = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/a/file.jpg');`

Comment: Bro you can't get the path on the front end as it's insecure - you need to do it via the backend. Any thoughts other than the __dirname?

Comment: @toby 's point is not that getting the path on the front-end is a good final solution - it's to isolate the specific behavior by using a fixed, hard-coded path to see if the file upload happens at all - that way you're testing (hopefully) only *one* behavior/code issue, not two or more...

Comment: ahh yeah I tried that - yeah it still didn't go through in a hard-coded absolute path to the file. The error is Error message: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/yoliz/Documents/identityImage.jpeg'